# MongoDB instance stops running on Webfaction

Tags: django, mongodb, webfaction

I am running MongoDB on Webfaction as a database of a Django app . Problem is I have to keep my SSH terminal session open and use this syntax to keep running MongoDB .

`mongod --dbpath ~/webapps/mongo_db/mongodb/ --port 31706`

As soon as I close my terminal the connection to database dies .  What is the solution to keep mongodb running always on server ?

Comment: `sudo service mongodb status` ?

Comment: this is an app runnuing on Webfaction server , when I do  service mongodb status it gives me this error : mongodb: unrecognized service

Comment: then check `mongod service` via `sudo service mongod status`

Comment: You installed from source which by default does not provide a init script. Instead you should follow the install instructions here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/ if you are unsure how  to make an init script, the packages come pre-loaded with one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebFaction is a shared host, so you can't run `mongod` as a system service.

Instead, use the `--fork` option when starting `mongod`, like so:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/webapps/mongo_db/mongodb/ --port 31706 --fork \
       --logpath $HOME/logs/user/mongo_db.log
```

When you need to stop it, run:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/webapps/mongo_db/mongodb/ --port 31706 --shutdown
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you were running a program that doesn't have a `--fork` option, you could also use `nohup`

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with :

mongod --dbpath ~/webapps/mongo_db/mongodb/ --port 31706 --fork \
       --logpath $HOME/logs/user/mongo_db.log

Also we can put a cron task to check it time to time .